# multiselect-react-dropdown | selected values not updating onRemove and onSelect function

Tags: reactjs, multi-select, multiselect-react-dropdown

Hi i am using multiselect-react-dropdown for selecting multiple options in my admin panel.

Getting relational data from API, which is working fine. now when i load/render the edit page the selectedValues variable got empty in first 4 attempts & on 5th attempt this variable fill by value. that is the reason selectedValues not updating in edit page. let me share code.

Edit.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import InputText from '../../../components/Input/InputText'
import { showNotification } from "../../common/headerSlice"
import { getCommonListings } from "../../../services/CommonService"
import TitleCard from "../../../components/Cards/TitleCard"
import MultiSelectBox from "../../../components/Input/MultiSelectBox"
import { showCategory, updateCategory } from "../../../services/CategoryService"
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import InputFile from "../../../components/Input/InputFile"
import InputSlug from "../../../components/Input/InputSlug"
import { NO_IMAGE } from "../../../utils/globalConstantUtil"
import { list } from "postcss"

const INITIAL_CATEGORY_OBJ = {
    id : "",
    title : "",
    slug : "",
    websites : [],
    image : ""
}

const getIDs = (arr) => {
    let ids = [];
    arr.forEach(ar => {
        ids.push(ar.id);
    });
   return ids;
}

function Edit(){
    const params = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [selectedWebsites, setSelectedWebsites] = useState([]);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState([])
    const [defaultImage, setDefaultImage] = useState("")
    const  websites  = useSelector(state => state.category.websites)
    const [categoryObj, setCategoryObj] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        
        dispatch(getCommonListings())
        dispatch(showCategory({...params}))
        .unwrap()
        .then(res => {

            let get_category_detail = res.data;
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_OBJ.id = get_category_detail.id;
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_OBJ.title = get_category_detail.title;
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_OBJ.slug = get_category_detail.slug;
            INITIAL_CATEGORY_OBJ.websites = getIDs(get_category_detail.websites);
            setCategoryObj(INITIAL_CATEGORY_OBJ);
            setDefaultImage(get_category_detail.image);
            setSelectedWebsites(get_category_detail.websites)
        })

    }, [])
    
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const doUpdate = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        console.log(categoryObj);
        dispatch(updateCategory({...categoryObj}))
        .unwrap()
        .then((res) => {
            if(res.success){
                dispatch(showNotification({message : res.message, status : 1}))
                navigate('/app/categories');
            }
            else{
                setErrorMessage(res.data)
                dispatch(showNotification({message : res.message, status : 0}))
            }
            setLoading(false);
            
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            dispatch(showNotification({message : e.message, status : 0}))
            setLoading(false);
        })
}

    const updateFormValue = ({updateType, value}) => {
        
        setCategoryObj({...categoryObj, [updateType]: value});
        
        if(updateType === 'title')
        setCategoryObj(prevState => ({...prevState, slug:value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()})) 
        
    }

    const updateFileValue = (file) => {
        if(!file) 
        return
        setCategoryObj({...categoryObj, image : file})
    }

    const setupMultiSelectList = ({updateType, listObj}) =>{
        setCategoryObj({...categoryObj, websites : listObj.map(lst => lst.id)})
    }

    return(
        <>
            
        <TitleCard title="Edit Category" topMargin="mt-2">     
            <InputText type="text" labelTitle="Title"  error={errorMessage['title'] ? errorMessage['title']:''} updateType="title" defaultValue={categoryObj.title} updateFormValue={updateFormValue}/>
            <InputSlug error={errorMessage['slug'] ? errorMessage['slug']:''} slug={categoryObj.slug} />
            <div className="mask mask-squircle w-12 h-12">
                <img src={defaultImage ?  process.env.REACT_APP_URL+defaultImage : NO_IMAGE}   alt="Avatar" />
            </div>
            <InputFile type="file" error={errorMessage['image'] ? errorMessage['image']:''}  updateType="image" containerStyle="mt-4" labelTitle="Image" updateFileValue={updateFileValue}/>
           
            <MultiSelectBox 
                labelTitle='Websites'  
                updateType="websites"
                selectedValues={selectedWebsites}
                options={websites}  
                error={errorMessage['websites'] ? errorMessage['websites']:''}
                setupMultiSelectList={setupMultiSelectList}
            />
            <div className="mt-16"><button className="btn btn-primary float-right" onClick={() => doUpdate()}>Update</button></div>
        </TitleCard>
        </>
    )
}


export default Edit
```

MultiSelectBox.js

```
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function MultiSelectBox({labelTitle, updateType, options, error, setupMultiSelectList, selectedValues}){
    
    console.log(selectedValues); //will show value on 5th attempt

    const [listObj, updateListObj] = useState(selectedValues);
    
    const onSelect = (selectedList, selectedItem) => { 
        updateListObj([...listObj, selectedItem])
    }
    const  onRemove = (selectedList, removedItem) => {
        updateListObj(listObj.filter(item => item.id !== removedItem.id));   
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setupMultiSelectList({updateType,listObj})
    },[listObj])

    return(
        <div className="form-control w-full">
            <label className="label">
                <span className="label-text text-base-content">{labelTitle}</span>
            </label>
            <Multiselect
                options={options} 
                onSelect={onSelect}
                onRemove={onRemove}
                displayValue="name"
                selectedValues={selectedValues}
            />
            {error ? 
            <span className="flex items-center font-medium tracking-wide text-red-500 text-xs mt-1 ml-1">
            {error}
            </span>:
            ''
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default MultiSelectBox
```

console output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix this.

```
 const [listObj, updateListObj] = useState(selectedValues);
    
    const onSelect = (selectedList, selectedItem) => { 
        updateListObj([...listObj, selectedItem])
    }
    const  onRemove = (selectedList, removedItem) => {
        updateListObj(listObj.filter(item => item.id !== removedItem.id));   
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setupMultiSelectList({updateType,listObj})
    },[listObj])
```

try this instead

```
    const onSelect = (selectedList, selectedItem) => { 
        setupMultiSelectList({updateType,[...listObj,selectedItem]})
    }
    const  onRemove = (selectedList, removedItem) => {
              setupMultiSelectList({updateType,[...listObj,selectedItem].filter(item => item.id !== removedItem.id)    })
```

remove the local state and useEffect you don't need that here

Comment: the main point to fill listObj initially, when component render.

Comment: the reason is you are setting the objList with empty selected Value and it is remaining empty try spreading objList and selectedValues every time as react keeps deep copy in state it won't notice any change use spread operator in the initial state setting as well 
useState([...selectedValues])